# Keycloak Postgres docker connection failure

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, keycloak

I am trying to get up the keycloak instance via using keycloak, and the compose file I used is below which I get it from

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/main/docker-compose-examples/keycloak-postgres.yml

```
# keycloak dependencies

  postgres-keycloak:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:legacy
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      # Uncomment the line below if you want to specify JDBC parameters. The parameter below is just an example, and it shouldn't be used in production without knowledge. It is highly recommended that you read the PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation in order to use it.
      #JDBC_PARAMS: "ssl=true"
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    depends_on:
      - postgres-keycloak


volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
```

When I run the file I am getting connection errors as below :

```
backend_services-keycloak-1           | Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
backend_services-keycloak-1           | Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "keycloak"
backend_services-keycloak-1           | 08:53:53,533 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database
backend_services-keycloak-1           | Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
backend_services-keycloak-1           | 08:53:54,449 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "metrics")]): java.lang.NullPointerException
backend_services-keycloak-1           | 08:53:54,460 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYSRV0022: Deploy of deployment "keycloak-server.war" was rolled back with no failure message
```

Answer (score 1):

This `docker-compose.yml` will be works.
You did a wrong two places (DB_ADDR and port forwarding)

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres-keycloak:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:legacy
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres-keycloak
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      # Uncomment the line below if you want to specify JDBC parameters. The parameter below is just an example, and it shouldn't be used in production without knowledge. It is highly recommended that you read the PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation in order to use it.
      #JDBC_PARAMS: "ssl=true"
    ports:
      - 8082:8080
    depends_on:
      - postgres-keycloak

volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
```

And open URL

```
http://localhost:8082/auth/
```

Click here then credential `admin`/`admin` (id / password)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if you want, Application named `test`,

Database login are, `keycloak:password`

keycloak admin login is : `root:root`

this will be accessible with a web browser at `localhost:8080`

```yaml
version: "3.8"
name: test
services:
    keycloak:
        image: jboss/keycloak:15.0.2
        environment:
            DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
            DB_ADDR: postgres
            DB_DATABASE: keycloak
            DB_USER: keycloak
            DB_SCHEMA: public
            DB_PASSWORD: password
            KEYCLOAK_USER: root
            KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: root
            KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME: keycloak
            # Uncomment the line below if you want to specify JDBC parameters. The parameter below is just an example, and it shouldn't be used in production without knowledge. It is highly recommended that you read the PostgreSQL JDBC driver documentation in order to use it.
            #JDBC_PARAMS: "ssl=true"
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        depends_on:
            - postgres   
        networks:
            - test
            
    postgres:
        image: postgres
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
            POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
        networks:
            - test    
            
            
        
volumes:
  postgres_data:
      driver: local  
      

networks:
  test:
    driver: bridge
```